# Wrong cross-reference format for sections using revtex4-1

Tags: cross-referencing, revtex

I am producing a document using the revtex4-1 document class, in which the sections should appear as, for example *I.A.1*. To achieve this, I've simply added the following lines to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

and it worked perfectly. The problem is now the following, if I add a reference to a section in the text, it appears as *I I.A I.A.1*. I tried various combinations, and this problem arises only when I add the two above lines using the revtex4-1 document class (for example, it behaves correctly using the *article* document class).
Here is a minimal working example to reproduce this problem:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\subsection{Some point}
\subsubsection{Some other point}
\label{sec:some_other_point}

\section{Outro}
As seen in Sec.~\ref{sec:some_other_point}, this reference is incorrectly shown using revtex4-1.

\end{document}
```

This renders like this using Texmaker (texLive) under Ubuntu 10.04.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `revtex4-1` class uses simple numbers in the headers, relying on the format for distinguishing among the section level: roman number and all caps bold face for sections, letter and boldface for subsections, arabic number and italics for subsubsections.

Thus it sets things up so that in references the missing bits are automatically supplied, via the associated macros `\p@subsection` and `\p@subsubsection`. Since you want to override the standard (which is a bit surprising, as the class is usually used for submissions to journals that have a predefined style), you have to say

```
\makeatletter
\def\p@subsection{}
\def\p@subsubsection{}
\makeatother
```

in your document preamble.

Comment: Nice and simple, that did the trick. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Class `reftex4-1` uses the feature that references can be prefixed using `\p@<counter>`.
You need to reset them for your redefined counters:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsubsection}{}
\makeatother
```